# How to refer the value of a cell in excel into a formula

Tags: excel, reference, cell, formula

I want to use the value of a cell in a reference formula.

For example:

I have a sheet with name '815108' which has all the data I need.

Now in the sheet1(new sheet), in A1 I type in ='815108'!A3 which gets the data from A3 in the sheet '815108'.

But the question I have -

In my new sheet 815108 is a defined attribute (For example: SO = 815108 is defined in cell F5.)
Instead of using '815108'!A3 I want to use the location in the current sheet. I tried ='=F5'!A3 which doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the few times that the [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) should be used:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & F5 & "'!A3")
```

INDIRECT is a volatile function that translates a string into a viable reference.

Being volatile it will re-calculate every time Excel re-calculates regardless if the data to which it refers has changed or not.

Comment: @Naga please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer,