# Referencing a sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel workbook with sheet tabs for data collected each month like "Nov 2016", "Dec 2016" and so on.
I have "Report" sheet tab that analyzes the data from the data sheet Nov 2016 with formulas referencing "Nov 2016" and the cells therein for data. 
I would like to be able to analyze data from "Dec 2016" if I change the cell A1 on "Report" to "Dec 2016".
What formula can I use to do this and to reference the data based on the month selected in "Report"? eg ='Nov 2016'!AN19 should change to ='Dec 2016'!AN19 if Dec 2016 is typed in cell A1.
Thankyou.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refer the value of a cell in excel into a formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226281/how-to-refer-the-value-of-a-cell-in-excel-into-a-formula)

Answer (score 0):

Put your sheet name in cell **A1** and in **B1** enter:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!A1" )
```

[image]